# how to protect my R code

Tags: c++, r

I am new to R.
Suppose I have an R code which takes certain real time inputs and gives output in real time.
I want to share it with a third party which uses C++ in such a way that the logic of my code is not seen but he will get output with the input he provides.

So here there are two things.
1: He uses C++ to give input
2: I have to somehow integrate my R code with his data in such a way that he can get only the output, not my logic

so my objective is two fold. One is integration with C++ and second is code protection.

How can this be done?

Comment: Set your code up as a "service" with RServe - http://rforge.net/Rserve/ and have folks pass it data over the network. It has a C++ library, so it should not be difficult for the third-party to integrate it into the workflow.

Comment: saw the dup SO post after my comment. Note that that thread was closed and found not valuable, so this one might endure the same fate.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: just write a server process that accepts incoming data via TCP and sends the responses back.  Run this on a separate machine, because otherwise the client will be able to gain access to your code.